# Why do lions keep young preys and don't kill them right away?

Tags: zoology, ethology

I saw some (actually several) videos on Youtube of young lions and lionesses that after hunting baby preys keep them and even seem to play with them. The lions don't seem to want to hurt them but they don't seem to want to let them go either. Most of the video titles are "lions protecting baby ....", I don't believe that. On the comments people say "the lion is saving it for later". My guess is that the lion wants to give the baby animal for the younger lions. What destiny will the baby prey most probably have?

Comment: Possibly to help the cubs learn how to hunt.  Cheetah will do this but I'm not sure about lions.  A quick google search only came up with this one newspaper article, with photos, but I didn't see a source for the article.  http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3429745/Taught-kill-mummy-Lion-cub-shown-hunt-lioness-wounds-prey-lets-youngster-finish-off.html

Comment: @Kurt I think you're probably right but the Daily Mail is probably one of the least reliable newspapers in the English language so I'd be wary about using it as a source :)

Comment: @Jam - Yeah, that's why I didn't want to use it as an answer.  I'm hoping somebody can find a scientific source to back it up.